# How to deliver websocket traffic from GCP load balancer to websocket server

Tags: load-balancing, libwebsockets, gcp-load-balancer

currently my websocket traffic is delivering from gcp load balancer to nginx to websocket server. am planning to remove one hop so that if i remove nginx. Then how to configure my websocket port (Reserved port) to gcp load balancer so that my websocket traffic will come from gcp load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is GCP load balancer support libwebsocket?
2. Can i configure my own port at GCP load balancer (except 443/80)

Comment: What kind of lb you trying to used ? Also what exactly you are trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Load Balancer setup today which supports WebSockets with the new TCP SSL Proxy Load Balancer from GCP.

Here's how:

1. You need to use SSL on the frontend configuration with your SSL
   certificate.
2. Then you need to have a TCP backend configuration pointing to your instance group and correct WebSocket port on your server.
3. You need to have session affinity enabled on the backend configuration.